# Proper syntax for summation of logarithms

Tags: summation, logarithms

In my textbook I found:

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\ln{(k)}=\log(1)+\log(2)+\log(3)+\cdots+\log(n)$$
Shouldn't it be:
$$=\ln(1)+\ln(2)+\ln(3)+\dotsb+\ln(n)\;\text?$$

Comment: Yeah.  If $\log$ means base $10$ then that statement is not at all true.  And if $\log$ means natural log (lots of texts do use that) then this is switching mid sentence which is wrong,pointless and confusing.

Comment: But I'm confused what the author is trying to illustrate.  Of course the sum symbol means the sum... what's the point of writing it out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely it is a typo, as using different notation $\ln$ and $\log$ in the same expression is bad style in my view.

However, it is not incorrect. The default base for the logarithm depends on the context, and very often it will be $2, 10$ or $e$.

Answer (score 2):

It's at least inconsistent, yes. That being said, in many textbooks $\log x$ actually means the natural logarithm.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested above, it  is not technically incorrect. You can always check the Errata (Google 'textbook name': Errata) - if one exists to see if this was an error.